# Autoscroll second frame

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm using a Webapp for editing webcontent. The Webapp uses multiple dynamic frames. On the left hand some images with links, where you can edit them on the right frame.

My old app which I uses cefsharp 53.0.1.0 and it works finde displaying an using this webapp.
For now I redesigned my app to the latest version of cefsharp.

The problem with the latest version, If I use in the Webapp the Link to edit something in the right frame, everytime I hit the link the right frame scrolls down automaticly some lines, with the 53 Version it stays at the position, which does the standalone chrome browser, too

Comment: Please provide an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Its very hard to find an example which is reachable by the public. The webapp used is only via user and password accessable.

Comment: You'll have to create an example that reproduces the problem,  describing the problem is insufficient. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm looking for that. What I figured out so far the editor used is CKEditor4. Furthermore the the Cefsharp.MinimalExample has the same behavior.

Comment: You should test with the CEF Sample application, the behaviour you are seeing is unlikely CefSharp specific.

Comment: I figured out some in the Log, on the frame that make the problems is a submit button, which saves the content an refreshes the frame. In the actual version the frame get empty after hitting that button. The log produces this message: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #", source: ...

Comment: Hi, analyzed the page with Chrome-Devtools, and my intention with standalone Chromebrowser was wrong: The error is there, too. The problem doesn't exists in Firefox an IE. Furthermore the problem for Chrome is this ckeditor.js:75 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write